# Visual Basic - Issue connecting forms and displaying input

Tags: vb.net, forms, module

I have a basic program I am writing for a project, where you order a candle. On a form (frm_Order) I have labels for input of name, address, zip etc. Then you hit proceed and it takes you to the next form. On that form it is a summary of the order both the customer information, and the contents of the cart (lst_cart) on the first form (frm_items).

I have two boxes summarizing the order where I would like the output to be the items that were in the cart as well as the input from the order form containing the customer information. How do I write the module to display those inputs from the previous forms? Also when it opens each proceeding form, how do I make the previous one close so that there aren't 3 windows open?

Comment: A module to make what work?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the (relevant) code that you have so far. This makes it easier for readers to understand which parts are missing and to provide an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I think you can achieve this within the forms, either on one of them or both. Instead of Module I think you can have Funtions to do that. I'm not to clear with the tools you have and the order on how you will display this on the form to display. You seem to have 3 forms and you haven't cleared what they do so will show you this using two forms.

The first form is where you will make your selection, then the second form is where you will see what you have selected on the first form with the client name and surname:

On form1 you need (will make this as simple as possible) 2 TextBox, one name it txtname then the second name it txtsurname.

Add a ComboBox and name it cmbitem
Add a button and name it btnorder

---

Now let's go to form2, I'm sure you have added it.
Add a label on top and name it lblorder_from
Add a listbox and name it lstitem
Add a button and call it close

Now let's begin coding.

Go back to form1 and double click the order button and enter this code.

```
 ' First check if textboxs are not null.
 If txtname.Text = "" Or txtsurname.Text = "" Then
 ' The textboxs or one of them has nothing typed so display error
 MsgBox("The fields can not be empty, please type something")
 Else
 ' We are good, textboxs are not null
 ' Declare our variables that we will use.
 Dim Name, Surname, Item As String ' You can also just not use this, instead just call the controls it self
 ' Assigning values to our variables
 Name = txtname.Text
 Surname = txtsurname.Text
 Item = cmbitem.SelectedItem.ToString
 ' Transfering data from this form to the second form.
 Form2.lblitem_from.Text = Name & " " & Surname & "'s order"
 lstitem.Items.Add(Item)
 ' Hide this form before showing the second form.
 Me.Visible = False
 ' Show the second form
 Form2.show
```

Now go to Form2 and double click the button close button and enter this code.

```
 Application.Exit()
 ' This will close all forms but if you used the "Close" it would close only form2 so you would need to make some changes on a project properties to enable that the project should close if form2 is closing because right not by defualt it is set to close only when form1 is closing.
```

Hope this gives you a picture on how you can transfer the items/data between the forms, you can run it now and ow you will have to add atleast one item on the ComboBox double click the form1 form to go to form_load() and enter this

```
 ' Add items to combobox
 cmbitem.Items.Add("Rice")
 cmbitem.Items.Add("Pie")
```

Then now you can run it, and fill in the controls and click order button to see.

The output should be, on the second form you should see a name and surname and on a list box you should see the item you selected. Only one form should be displayed at a time as you requested.